# English idiom for "After us it may flood"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

There is an idiom in Russian "После нас хоть потоп" that can be roughly translated as "After us it may flood". It means the speaker doesn't care what happens after his leave (more often implying death rather than actually going elsewhere) to the place he leaves behind. Usually it's not actually said aloud, but attributed to others to denote their attitude. Example usage:

*He doesn't care how much trouble this contract will cause to the company ten years down the line. With his retirement coming in a year, he probably thinks to himself: "______________________".*

Answer (score 3):

**After me, the deluge.**
This is the standard translation of "Après moi, le deluge," frequently attributed to Louis XV of France. In very formal writing, you could use the French original.

Comment: It's usually not attributed to the king, but to his chief mistress. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_de_Pompadour

Comment: The French version is not limited to "very formal writing" in my opinion.